# Financial proof papers for schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen

Please confirm, while showing financial proof is it mandatory to show only one's salary account or any other bank account? The thing is I keep transferring money from my salary account to my savings account with another bank every month.

Answer (score 7):

The point of "financial proof" is to demonstrate that you have a stable financial position.  The best way to do that is to submit statements from all of your bank accounts.

If you show only your salary account, the official evaluating your application may wonder about the monthly outgoing transfers.  If they thought to be some monthly expense, then they would be seen to reduce your capacity to pay for your trip.

On the other hand, if you show only your savings account, the official will wonder where that money is coming from, and whether it is legitimate.  If its legitimacy is under question, then they may refuse to grant a visa.